# Vue JS Roles & Permission in a table grid using checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, permissions, vuetify.js, roles

I would like to check permissions of a role using checkbox in vue. For example if an admin can create, view, delete a checkbox will be selected, if not checkbox will not be selected. So far i have the table created with proper roles and permissions that below to each role but don't know how to check checkbox based on permission in role.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data() {
    return {
    
    
permissions: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "view posts"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "create posts"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        "name": "edit posts"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "delete posts"
    }
],
roles: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "admin",
        description: "Full admin access to all the areas of the blog.",
        permissions: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "view posts",  
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "create posts",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "edit posts",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "delete posts",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "executive",
        description: "Limited access to critical areas of the blog",
        permissions: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "view posts",   
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "create posts",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "user",
        description: "Basic view access to some areas of the blog",
        permissions: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "view posts",
            }
        ]
    }
]

     
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
        
<div id="app">

<template>

<div>

<div id='permissionsTable'>
                <v-row class='headerRow'>
                  <v-col cols='3'>Permissions</v-col>
                  <v-col v-for="role in roles" v-bind:key="role.id">{{role.name}}</v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row v-for="permission in permissions" v-bind:key="permission.id" class="bodyRow">
                  <v-col cols='3'>{{permission.name}}</v-col>
                  <v-col v-for="(role, index) in roles" v-bind:key="role.name">

                    {{roles[index].permissions}}

                      <v-checkbox :input-value="roles[index].permissions.includes(permission.id)" @change="onItemClick($event,role.name,permission.id)">
                </v-checkbox>
               
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </div>

</div>

</template>

 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this help.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    onItemClick(e, role, permissionId) {
      const index = this.roles.findIndex((r) => r.name === role);
      const found=this.roles[index].permissions.find(perm=> perm.id === permissionId)
      if (
        found
      ) {
        this.roles[index].permissions.splice(
          this.roles[index].permissions.findIndex(perm=>perm.id===permissionId),
          1
        );
      } else {
        this.roles[index].permissions.push(this._permissions[permissionId]);
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    _permissions() {
      return this.permissions.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const id = curr.id;
        acc[id] = curr;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    },
    _roles() {
      return this.roles.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const id = curr.id;
        acc[id] = curr;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      permissions: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "view posts"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "create posts"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "edit posts"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "delete posts"
        }
      ],
      roles: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "admin",
          description: "Full admin access to all the areas of the blog.",
          permissions: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "view posts"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "create posts"
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: "edit posts"
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: "delete posts"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "executive",
          description: "Limited access to critical areas of the blog",
          permissions: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "view posts"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "create posts"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "user",
          description: "Basic view access to some areas of the blog",
          permissions: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "view posts"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <template>

    <div>
      <div id='permissionsTable'>
        <v-row class='headerRow'>
          <v-col cols='3'>Permissions</v-col>
          <v-col v-for="role in roles" v-bind:key="role.id">{{role.name}}</v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row v-for="permission in permissions" v-bind:key="permission.id" class="bodyRow">
          <v-col cols='3'>{{permission.name}}</v-col>
          <v-col v-for="(role, index) in roles" v-bind:key="role.name">

            {{roles[index].permissions}}

            <v-checkbox :input-value="_roles[role.id].permissions.find(perm=>perm.id===permission.id)" @change="onItemClick($event,role.name,permission.id)">
            </v-checkbox>

          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </div>

    </div>

  </template>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input here, I'm not looking to have disabled boxes but instead just have check in each of the checkbox, the goal is to assign a new permission to a role or remove a permission to a role just by selecting or deselecting checkbox. Thanks

Comment: code updated.. let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: modified the arrays and now nothing works, could you please update the code again? Thank you!!!

Comment: code updated. please check and let me know if you find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

`v-checkbox` has a `v-model` prop that you can use to pass Boolean and select or deselect it accordingly ! try adding that Boolean in your `roles` array and use it inside the `v-for`. you can also check your condition inside `v-for` on `v-model` like `:v-model="role.permissions.includes(1)"` but it's up to you to use the one that suit your case best.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i know there is a v-model that can be use, i just dont understand why there should be a boolean value inside roles. Makes no sense

Comment: the above answer is a bit too much work for something that can be done very simply in my opinion , you want to check some of the checkboxes , so you can add that Boolean and set it to `v-model` and use true or false values for checking and unchecking each item . you can also do without the Boolean by putting the logic (like `:v-model="role.permissions.includes(1)"`) directly inside `v-model`if you want.